# Common Knowledge Theory vs Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, game-theory

In the theory of knowledge and common knowledge, an *event* is any subset $E$ of a sample space $\Omega$. For a given partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $\Omega$, it is said that an agent *knows* event $E$ at $\omega\in\Omega$ if $\mathcal{P}(\omega)\subseteq E$, where $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ denotes the partition cell to which $\omega$ belongs.

In measure theory, an *event* is an element of a $\sigma$-algebra. Can we say that knowledge of an event is equivalent to saying that it belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the given partition $\mathcal{P}$ or are events in measure theory and in common knowledge theory different objects?

Comment: “Common knowledge theory”? Can you provide some references for context.

Comment: It sounds like CKT (unfamiliar to me) adds to what m.t. includes something extra: a distinguished measure-theoretic atomic element  $\omega$ that represents reality or is some belief about what is real according to a knower.  Or maybe the measure-theoretic atoms are the psrtition members, and $\omega$s are indexes of them.  Either way, so far as I understand it, to me  CKT sounds like it's consistent with m.t., but adds an additional bit of structure.  (I know quite a bit about theory of knowledge in philosophy, but this is new to me.)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. An event is any element from a given $\sigma$-algebra, not the one generated by the partition. It is not true that agent knows $E$ whenever $E$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the partition. Here is a simple example.

Let $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4\}$. Endow $\Omega$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$. Consider the partition $\mathcal{P}=\{\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}\{\omega_3, \omega_4\}\}$. It generates the following $\sigma$-algebra: $\sigma(\mathcal{P})=\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{\omega_1, \omega_2\}\{\omega_3, \omega_4\}\}$. Now consider event $E=\{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3\}$. At $\omega=\omega_1$, agent knows $E$ because $\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)\subset E$. But it is not true that $E\in\sigma(\mathcal{P})$.

Comment: Nice example. This paper might be of interest: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~fede/published/dubra-echenique-mbility.pdf